# Rubber Rails PG::ConnectionBad not connect to EC2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2, capistrano, rubber

After update to rubber 3.1.0 and using postgres 9.3 on a 3.2.22 rails app i'm trying to deploy on Ec2 is showing this on the log:

```
** [out :: app01.foo.com] PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.35.45.216", user "foo", database "foo_production", SSL on
** [out :: app01.foo.com] 
** [out :: app01.foo.com] FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "172.35.45.216", user "foo", database "foo_production", SSL off
```

someone got the same problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/83984/connect-to-postgresql-server-fatal-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host?

Comment: no because this is a rubber ec2 issue

Comment: @dcalixto If you're looking for a bug fix in the rubber gem, you should open an issue on their github page.

Comment: well, someone got the same problem, and know the fix